Scrapy and Great Expectations (great_expectations) - Not working together
I am trying to use the packages scrapy and great_expectations within the same virtual environment. There seems to be an issue with the compatibility between the two packages, depending on the order in which I import them in.
Example:

I created a virtual environment and pip installed the latest version of each package.

Does work:
import great_expectations
import scrapy

print("done")

Does not work:
import scrapy
import great_expectations

print("done")

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 

"/Users/grant/vs_code_projects/grants_projects/test_environment.py", line 2, in <module>
    import great_expectations
  File "/Users/grant/Envs/test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/great_expectations/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    register_core_expectations()
  File "/Users/grant/Envs/test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/great_expectations/expectations/registry.py", line 187, in register_core_expectations
    from great_expectations.expectations import core  # noqa: F401
  File "/Users/grant/Envs/test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/great_expectations/expectations/core/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .expect_column_distinct_values_to_be_in_set import (
  File "/Users/grant/Envs/test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/great_expectations/expectations/core/expect_column_distinct_values_to_be_in_set.py", line 12, in <module>
    from great_expectations.expectations.expectation import (
  File "/Users/grant/Envs/test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/great_expectations/expectations/expectation.py", line 2350, in <module>
    class BatchExpectation(Expectation, ABC):
  File "/Users/grant/Envs/test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/great_expectations/expectations/expectation.py", line 287, in __new__
    newclass._register_renderer_functions()
  File "/Users/grant/Envs/test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/great_expectations/expectations/expectation.py", line 369, in _register_renderer_functions
    attr_obj: Callable = getattr(cls, candidate_renderer_fn_name)
AttributeError: __provides__

Edit:

I have tried all major versions of Scrapy (current version, 2.0.0, 1.0.0) with all major versions of Great Expectations and it is the same result.


Digging into this just now, this highly likely has something to do with scrapy's dependence on zope.interface, which seems to be (somehow) overriding __dir__ on great-expectation's objects. I haven't yet been able to figure out when or why this is happening in this case.

If I change the line "attr_obj: Callable = getattr(cls, candidate_renderer_fn_name)" to "attr_obj: Callable = getattr(cls, candidate_renderer_fn_name, None)" it does allow the import of the packages to take place.

This has been fixed as of 0.18.13
https://github.com/great-expectations/great_expectations/releases/tag/0.18.13
